# Can't use ADO.NET Entity Data Model

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

In C# on .NET 7.0, I can't add an ADO.NET Entity Data Model to my proejct. When I try, I get this error:

[image]

I installed these packages in my project:

[image]

Comment: Yes, of course you can use ADO.NET on .NET 7 - `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataReader` all work just fine. But I suspect you're trying to add something else here - can you tell us ***WHAT EXACTLY*** you're trying to add to your project?

Comment: I'm trying add a ADO.NET entity data model,but show me that error

Comment: .NET Core does no longer support the model-driven approach for Entity Framework (Core). You need to use either a code-first, code-driven approach, or you need to reverse engineer an existing database into data classes.

Comment: If you are using EF Core, please do not try to use the model-driven approach. dbfirst and codefirst provided by EF Core are more convenient to use. For details, please refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli